# Log to File not found in magento 2.3.6-p1

Tags: magento2.3.6-p1

I am trying to use log of magento 2, it's documentation said I have to set "Yes" to "Log to file" in store/configuration/developer/debug. But at there I can't find Log to file drowdown. My magento version is 2.3.6-p1. And suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/logging.html, you should run the command `bin/magento setup:config:set --enable-debug-logging=true && bin/magento cache:flush` in order to enable debug logging.